# Prove $b > 0 \implies b^3 + 3b > 3b^2$ in any ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ordered-fields

Prove $b > 0 \implies b^3 + 3b > 3b^2$ in any ordered field.  Prove this algebraically (i.e. without continuity or IVT).

Using analysis, this is easy.  Is there a way to prove it without analysis or limits, but simply using algebra?

I believe there must be, because I believe that any ordered field would have this property, even if it is incomplete.

If not: does this imply that there exists ordered fields which do not have this property?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be able to show $b^3-3b^2+3b>0$ by completing the square to get $b^2-3b+3>0$?

Comment: By the AM/GM, $b^3+3b\geq 2b^2\sqrt 3>3b^2$ since $2\sqrt3>3.$ But if this comes from the other problem, this is not the inequality you need.

Comment: Or, since $b > 0$, we have $b - 1 > -1$ and $(b - 1)^3 > -1$ (since $x \mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing). Expand and rearrange this, and you get the desired inequality.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\sqrt3$ doesn't exist in an arbitrary ordered field

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can square both sides if necessary. @Kenta You get $(b^3+3b)^2\geq 12b^2>9b^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
b^2-3b+3=b^2-3b+\frac94+3-\frac94
=(b-\frac32)^2+\frac34>0.
$$
Since $b>0$ multiplying by $b$ preserves the inequality. Then
$$
b^3-3b^2+3b>0. 
$$

Comment: Simple and clear.  This also makes apparent the generalization: $b^2 - pb + q = (b - \frac p 2)^2 - \frac p 4 + q > 0 \iff p < 4q$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we want to show that $b^3 > 3b^2-3b = 3b(b-1)$. We can eliminate $b < 1$ easily since $b^3 > 0$ but if $b -1 < 0$ we have $3b(b-1) < 0$ and it is also trivial to check when $b=1$. This leaves the case when $b > 1$ and so we write $b=c+1$ for some $c > 0$. Now substituting gives $$3b^2-3b=3(c^2+2c+1)-3(c+1) = 3c^2-c < c^3 + 3c^2 + 3c+ 1 = (c+1)^3=b^3$$

And so we have $3b^2 -3b < b^3$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach it.

Since $b > 0$, we can apply the AM-GM inequality to conclude the desired claim:
\begin{align*}
b + \frac{3}{b} \geq 2\sqrt{3} > 3 \Rightarrow b + \frac{3}{b} > 3 & \Rightarrow b^{3} + 3b > 3b^{2}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this help!